# HTML & CSS - Multiple Tiered Lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How can I recreate via HTML & CSS a list that would have item bullets such as:

```
1 Definitions and ...
 1.1 Test 123
 1.2 Smile 23
   1.2.1 Test 23
2 Fed
 2.1 Fes
 etc...
```

When I try

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h5>Definitions and Examples of Academic Dishonesty. </h5>
    <ol>
      <li>Test 123</li>
      <li>Smile 23
        <ol>
          <li>Test 23</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>fed
    <ol>
      <li>fes</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I get the following output which is not what we want:
[image: Stacked Listing]